# Unknown column '' in 'field list'. Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using Django 1.9 and MySQL. I want to rename a field in my model. Let's look at model `Choice` from the [Django getting started tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/).

```
class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

So, I want to rename the `votes` field to `votes_count`. I created an empty migration and add to operations following line:

```
migrations.RenameField (
    model_name='choice',
    old_name='votes',
    new_name='votes_count',
),
```

After `python manage.py migrate`, the field in the database table was renamed. But when I tried to use this model

```
def vote(request, question_id):
  question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id);
  try:
    selected = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
  except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
      'question':question,
      'error_message':"You didn't select a choice."
    })
  else:
    selected.votes_count += 1
    selected.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question_id)))
```

I got:

> Unknown column 'polls_choice.votes' in 'field list

```
    Traceback:

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
      112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
      226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
      36.         raise errorvalue

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
      217.             res = self._query(query)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in
_query
      378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in
_do_query
      341.         db.query(q)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
      280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

    The above exception ((1054, "Unknown column 'polls_choice.votes' in 'field list'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "./polls/views.py" in vote
      23.     selected = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
      122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
      381.         num = len(clone)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
      240.         self._fetch_all()

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
      1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
      52.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
      848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in
__exit__
      95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
      685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
      112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
      226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
      36.         raise errorvalue

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
      217.             res = self._query(query)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in
_query
      378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in
_do_query
      341.         db.query(q)

    File "/home/verdigo/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
      280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

    Exception Type: OperationalError at /polls/1/vote/
    Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'polls_choice.votes' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I don't think it is coming from this view.

Comment: Did you change `votes` to `votes_count` in your models after running the migration?

Comment: or forgot old column name in admin.py ?

Comment: Include the full traceback, please. I often forget to change my admin.py when renaming stuff in models.py.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks as if you created and ran a migration to rename the model field from `votes` to `votes_count`, but did not update the model at the same time.

When the Django tries to fetch the model from the db, it tries to select the `votes` column because you still have a votes field in your models, and you get the error because the column doesn't exist in the database.

Creating a manual migration isn't normally necessary. Usually, you would rename the model field, run `makemigrations`, then run `migrate`. The advantage of letting Django create the migration is that you can be confident that the database is in sync with your models after you have run migrate.

Comment: Thank you. It was something with app. `makemigrations` didn't detect any changes in models.. I've recreated app, and now it works fine.

Comment: @verdigo is there app and you run python manage.py startapp yourapp?

Comment: I started to feel Django migrations system is unreliable

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that has persisted with me and lead me down a lot of rabbit holes dropping tables etc. A simple solution I have found is answering "N" when django asks you if you are renaming a field of that model (when running makemigrations). What that then essentially performs is a deletion of your previous field and creates the new field. Be careful as you may lose data on existing field so this works with fields which are either new or relatively easy to 'refill' their data required. You may need to run  --fake if you get an error with regards to not being able to 'drop field' when migrating after makemigrations.

Update:
I did the above for a Boolean field and my data was kept. Even though I said N, it seems as if it is essentially a renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Cause: This error occurs when a new one-to-many foreign key is created, pointing to the model with the forkey field and then generating the table

.

Solution: This problem can be solved by directly deleting the database and rebuilding it.

1: drop database database table;

2, re-create after deletion, before the code created, run directly

Comment: What happens to the data of the database, just drop it? :|||

Comment: I did it and errors solved. but this is not a good solution. All data will deleted. there is not a good and easy method for this problem yet or i cannot find it.

Comment: Deleting a database should not be an option to fix issues related to migrations. I ran into the same issue and I updated the relevant column names in the database directly. After running the migration again, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

On my end it occured when I added a new column with a oneToMany relationship and the migration failed to pick it up.
To avoid deleting data and recreating the models, Download mysql workbench for your platform. The run the following code to insert the missing column.

```
use <database_name>;
show tables;
desc <table_name>;
alter table <table_name> add column (< missing field> varchar(255) )
```

That added the missing colum and the error went away