# python Django db utils programming error (1064)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json NOT NULL, `category_json` json NOT NULL)' at line 1")**

*occurs during the database migrations in python sharehosting*

Comment: apparently you have different versions mysql on the old and new hosting. Now you need to find the places where there is an error and manually fix them (in the dump)

Comment: error is because of different in migration instance in dump sql file form the local machine has different migration then in hosting site which actually generate this kind of error i have the cause number 3 which is in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65747056/10809057) ..... which